# What was the meaning of the note "John was beside you."?

Tags: plot-explanation, holding-the-man

In the movie *Holding the Man*, near the end Tim sees the note "John was beside you."

What was this note? Who really gave it and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holding_the_Man_(film)), it's a callback to the start of the movie:

> In 1993, Timothy Conigrave (Ryan Corr) is in Lipari, Italy, and he calls his childhood friend Pepe Trevor (Sarah Snook) on a payphone in a panic, **asking her where his deceased partner John Caleo (Craig Stott) was sitting at a dinner party they had together when they were teenagers**. The time expires before Pepe can tell him. Later, **a concierge at the hotel Tim is staying at passes on a message from Pepe to Tim.**

At the end of the film:

> The film returns to the beginning, and Pepe phones Tim's hotel. We see the note from earlier says "John was beside you."